# Symfony swiftmailer documentation configuration not working

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I am starting with symfony (I use the last version i.e. 5)
I tested the configuration shown in the documentation to send mail with swiftmailer

Here is the configuration in **.env**

> MAILER_URL=smtp://fox.o2switch.net:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=symfony@mydomain.fr&password=mypassword

and here is the test controller I use

> ```
> class MailerController extends AbstractController {
> /**
>  * @Route("/mailer",name="mailer")
>  */
> public function sendEmail( \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
> {
>
>     $email = (new \Swift_Message('Message de test configuration 1'))
>                 ->setFrom(array('symfony@denentzat.fr'=> 'Configuration 1'))
>                 ->setTo('me.me@domain.org')
>                 ->setCharset('utf-8')
>                 ->setBody(
>                'Hello from symfony!'
>             );
>
>     $sentEmail = $mailer->send($email);
>
>     // ...
>
>     return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
> }
> ```

With this configuration **it doesn't work**. Thus I tried this new Controller

```
public function sendEmail( )
{

$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('fox.o2switch.net', 587))
  ->setUsername('symfony@mydomain.fr') 
  ->setPassword('mypassword') 
;
$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

$email = (new \Swift_Message('Message de test configuration 2'))
            ->setFrom(array('symfony@denentzat.fr'=> 'Configuration 2'))
            ->setTo('me.me@domain.org')
            ->setCharset('utf-8')
            ->setBody(
           'Hello from symfony!'
        );


$sentEmail = $mailer->send($email);

// ...

return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
```

}

With this configuration, **I receive the mails !**

**My question : what am I missing in the symfony documentation for configuration 1 ?**

Answer (score 1):

The trouble was due to a password needing a urlencode treatment  due to the use of special char +.
Original password +.... replaced with %2B....